# Refresh the pages

Tags: android

I am developing the chatting application but by using that application two persons are not received chatting messages properly.If one person send a chat message to other did not receive it immediately .For that i want the refresh that application For that what can i do?Give me some suggestion .Thanks in advance

Comment: Are developing a web page that you want to refresh every 60 seconds, or make and extension for use on android that lets you make any page refresh every 60 seconds?

Comment: your question covers large area. so please be specific....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all declare the WebView control globally in your activity.

```
WebView wvWebView;
```

Now load the web page into the

```
//created an instance of the webview from the XML layout.
wvWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

//then open your web page in the web view
wvWebView.loadUrl("http://....");

//now schedule a timer which will reload/refresh the page every 60 seconds.
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             wvWebView.reload();
        }}, 60000, 60000);
```

I hope this will help you.